# Return an object graph from a linq query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a `Vehicle` model:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ...
    public IEnumerable<VehiclePolicy> Policies { get; set; }
}
```

and a `VehiclePolicy` model:

```
public class VehiclePolicy
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

    public DateTime EffectiveFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EffectiveTo { get; set; }
}
```

And the EF Core 5 datasets:

```
public virtual DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<VehiclePolicy> VehiclePolicies { get; set; }
```

When I perform a linq query:

```
from v in _context.Vehicles
join vp in _context.VehiclePolicies on v.ID equals vp.VehicleID into vvp
from vehiclePolicy in vvp.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby v.Title
select new Vehicle 
{
  ID = v.ID,
  Title = v.Title,
  ...
  Policies = vehiclePolicy
}
```

Is there an easier way to return the `Vehicle` graph, rather than having to compose it “manually”?

Answer (score 0):

Actually exactly for this purpose EF introduced `Include`:

```cs
var query = context.Vehicles
    .Include(v => v.Policies)
    .OrderBy(v => v.Title);
```